# Are OpenGL binary program formats standardized?

Tags: opengl, binary, shader

I've been googling around OpenGL binary formats and what they actually are/mean.  So far I've not had much success.  I know I can fetch the number and set of formats as follows:

```
::glGetIntegerv(GL_PROGRAM_BINARY_FORMATS, &values[0]);
```

, where values is a std::vector of integers of size:

```
::glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_PROGRAM_BINARY_FORMATS, &value);
```

For the driver in my machine this returns a single binary format.  It's just a number and is pretty meaningless to me otherwise.

So my questions are as follows:

(1) What do the format numbers/codes represent?
(2) Are there standard ARB binary formats, or are they all vendor dependent?
(3) Is there a common format between vendors?
(4) If there are multiple formats, how are you supposed to choose between them?

I have a vague feeling I have to pre-compile and cache shaders on a given machine in order to take advantage of this.  I mean it isn't like DX is it, where you can run the shader compiler as a post-build event and package them together and use them on any (Windows) machine with D3D.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> (1) What do the format numbers/codes represent?

They represent unique identifiers.

> (2) Are there standard ARB binary formats, or are they all vendor dependent?

They are all vendor specific.

> (3) Is there a common format between vendors?

No.

> (4) If there are multiple formats, how are you supposed to choose between them?

You don't. You don't get a choice of formats. When you call [`glGetProgramBinary`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetProgramBinary), you get binary data in a particular format decided by the driver. When you [load that program later](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glProgramBinary), you must pass that specific format with the binary data.

> I have a vague feeling I have to pre-compile and cache shaders on a given machine in order to take advantage of this.

Yes, that's the purpose of the feature: to allow you to cache shader compilation. But you must always make sure that your program will work if the driver's shader version *changes* (and therefore is different from when you created the cached version). So you'll still need to be able to rebuild the shaders from the textual form.